# ActionScript 3: How to render different sprites at different quality on the same stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have the ingame sprite and it needs to be in StageQuality.LOW due to some prerformance problems, and the hud needs to be in StageQuality.HIGH... but they are in the same stage. I tried changing quality before rendering the ingame (to a big bitmapdata) but changing this property every frame is too expensive.

Comment: Before trying to change the quality of the rendering, you should be trying to optimise your code so that there aren't any performance problems. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible - the Stage quality is not just a simple variable saying which objects to draw good, which not...

The Stage quality is directly passed to Flash renderer, which then renders the objects, graphics and everything depending on it.

So - you can not specify a quality FOR an object, there is always just one quality.

I guess that your "ingame Sprite" is some kind of holder, right? So... What about doing some render culling? That is, do not render anything that you can not even see. That might improve it just a little bit... But without more code I (we?) can not help you more...

Comment: ok, i have a game sprite (where everything is drawn with bitmapdatas, except for the fog of war alghorithm which uses vectorial shapes drawn into a bitmapdata), it runs at 110 fps in low quality and 80 in high quality but the game (not the hud) looks identical... so i will use bitmaps for the hud instead of vectorial graphics. thanks

Comment: If everything except the effects are drawn using BitmapDatas, quality will affect only these effects. BitmapData (Bitmap) is just rendered the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Stage quality is global, AFAIK it's not possible to have two sprites at different quality. Maybe you need to optimize some other way. Describe your problem so we can think on it.